# How to give div a class based on the route with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, templates

I've got a simple angular template which does a simple ng-repeat containing some divs. I now want to give a containing div a class if the `$routeParams.userId` equals  the id of the object in the loop. See the second line of the code below to see what I mean.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
    <div class="col-xs-12 contact-wrapper {{ if ($routeParams.userId == contact.id){ print 'active' } }}"> <!-- <== SOMETHING LIKE THIS -->
        {{ contact.user_name }}
        <br />{{ contact.last_pm_text }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how I can give the div the class `active` when the `contact.id` equals the `$routeParams.userId`? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by using `ng-class`

```
<div class="col-xs-12 contact-wrapper" ng-class="{'active' :  (userIdx == contact.id)}">
```

and **in your controller** get the userId in route params in to a scope variable `userIdx`, because angular not allowed to use `$routeParams` inside the html

```
$scope.userIdx = $routeParams.userId;
```

[angularjs Doc says,](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use ng-class:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div class="col-xs-12 contact-wrapper" ng-class="{'active' : $routeParams.userId == contact.id}"> 
        {{ contact.user_name }}
        <br />{{ contact.last_pm_text }}
</div>
```